# js jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have been using a jquery slideshow, but when I include a jquery newsticker (text that scrolls to the right) either the slideshow or the menu javascript popup (or both) do not work. For instance, if I put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

right above the slideshow script, the slidshow works but something else does not. If I put the code inside the head tag, its the other way around. This is very unusual (and not logical), but Ive been troubled with this stuff for 6 hours. I am sure this is the only link to jquery, besides a prototype.js that works with the menu. However, I am simply editing the website so I do not know how everything works.

Does anyone have an idea about what may be the solution?

The other way I can deal with this is by using a javascript slideshow (but no jquery).
But I cant find an example of what I want, that works without jquery.

What I need is this - php gets all images from a folder, and data (links) from the database. Each image is actually a link, and all images are displayed inside a div.

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <a href="link"> <img src="src.jpg"> </a>
  <a href="link"> <img src="src.jpg"> </a>
  <a href="link"> <img src="src.jpg"> </a>
</div>
```

div id slideshow is what the javascript (again, not jquery) uses to know what to cycle (fade animation). Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Have you checked the Firebug or Chrome console for error messages?

Comment: Try this code of mine: http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/

Comment: Reference: *I am sure this is the only link to jquery* Solution: Confirm your assumption by checking the **Network Tab** in Chrome or **Net Tab** in Firfox/Firebug to see if jQuery is loaded more than once as an asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other libraries like prototype and mootools also share the same "$" alias so when combined in same page they conflict.

You will need to use jQuery.noConflict() to resolve.

In a script tag immediately after jQuery loads call:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now in order to continue using "$" in your code, wrap code in:

```
  jQuery(function($){/* $ argument passes use of $ alias for jQuery into function*/

      $(selector).hide() ; /* can use normal jQuery syntax inside this function*/

  });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries